# Context aware SharePoint custom action in a form library

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, custom-action, infopath-2007

I'm trying to create a custom view for creating reports based on InfoPath form items which have been submitted to a SharePoint Form Library.

I want to

> 1. expose a checkbox next to each list item in a list view
> 2. create a custom action in the Actions menu titled "Create Report"
> 3. when the action button is clicked, run code which is aware of the checked boxes

I am sure there is good documentation on how to create a custom action.

But how would you expose a checkbox alongside list items in a view?
And how can you determine which items were checked when running the custom action code?

The functionality in the form library "Relink Documents" view is similar to what I would like to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blog post "[Select Multiple List Items in SharePoint Feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/05/select-multiple-list-items-in-sharepoint-feature.aspx)" covers exactly what you want and shows step-by-step instructions including code to have a checbox column and a custom action that [zips selected items and downloads them](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/03/09/downloadaszip-sharepoint-feature-part-ii.aspx).